# Trying to separate a ceiling fan, kitchen light, and outside light

Tags: lighting

I have these three lights and only two switches in my house built in the 60s. I have one light switch that controls the outside light and one switch that controls the ceiling fan and kitchen light.

When I opened up the switch box I had three white (neutral) wires wire nutted together. Then I had two black wires on one switch, a black wire connecting the switches, and the other black wire on the other switch.

One switch controls the kitchen light and living room ceiling fan. The other only controls the light outside. I would like to separate the two and put them on two switches.

Therefore I would have three switches. When I tried to wire them singly nothing worked. What else can I try?

Comment: you know what switch doses what.

Comment: I just know the one on the right only controls the outside light and the one on the left control both the ceiling fan and kitchen light fixture.

Answer (score 1):

You have three black wires,
one comes from, the breaker (and goes to both switches via the link wire)
one goes to the outdoor light
one goes to the kitchen fan and light.

You need another wire from the fan location to the switch location.

It's probably easier to get a pull-string operated fan.

Comment: It is a pull string ceiling fan. The problem is that the kitchen light has 5 light bulbs and has to be on when the ceiling fan is running. That’s what I am trying to avoid. So what you are saying is another wire from the ceiling fan to the box? One hit wire for all three lights is what I have then?

Comment: fit LED bulbs, they cost basically nothing to run.

Comment: Can't be done Robert. Its a boneheaded circuit layout. You could consider putting the light on a motion sensor as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for all the ideas and yes I know it is a boneheaded circuit. Don’t know why someone would wire it that way. I am going to install a pull chain on the kitchen light fixture to just pull it to cut it off.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a bit bigger project than you're expecting. If I understand correctly, you want to add a 3rd switch to the box on the wall that will operate the living room fan/light separately from the kitchen light (the outside light is only involved because it happens to be in the current 2-gang box).

To make this happen:

First find out how the wiring is making it from the kitchen light to the living room light.

- Turn off the breaker powering this circuit
- Remove the kitchen light from the ceiling and take a careful look at the wiring.

  - You should find one cable coming into the box from the switch
  - It should be connected to a 2nd cable leaving the box that carries power on to the living room
  - It should also be connected to the kitchen fixture
- Label the two cables with something like:

  - "Kitchen light"
  - "Living Room light"

Now it's time to start disconnecting wiring.

- Turn off the breaker feeding power to this 2-gang box (or make sure it's still off).
- Carefully label the cables coming into the box. You'll need labels for:

  - "Hot from panel"
  - "Switched to outside"
  - "Switched to kitchen"
- Disconnect all the wires from all the switches.
- Pull the 2-gang box out of the wall.

  - If this is a "new work" box, it's likely nailed or screwed to a stud. You may have to open up a bigger hole in the wall to get the box removed.
  - If it's an "old-work" box, there will be screws/clamps holding it to the wall surface and it will be easier to remove.
- Remove all the wires from the old 2-gang box.

  - If it's a metal box, it's simply loosening the screws on the cable clamps and pulling the wires out
  - If it's a plastic box with flexible plastic clamps built in, you'll have to *very* carefully pry the clamps further open to push the cable out without damaging the cable sheath.

You now have the old switch removed from the wall and cables dangling in the wall. If you've used all your work time for the day, put a small wire nut (probably yellow or orange in color) on each individual wire to protect and insulate any exposed copper (except for the bare or green grounds - they're fine to leave alone). At this point, you can turn the breaker back on if you need to in order to power other items on this circuit for the evening/next morning.

Now is the most difficult step:

- Turn the breaker for this circuit off.
- You will have to fish a new cable from this location, up the wall, across the ceiling to the kitchen light mounting location and into the ceiling box.
- You'll want to label this cable "Living room" *at both ends* so that once it's in the wall you'll know which cable is which.
- Note that you now have a new cable in this ceiling box. You'll need to be sure that you're not exceeding box fill rules.

  - According to [this box fill calculator](https://www.constructionmonkey.com/calculations/misc/boxfill)<sup>*</sup>, you'll need a minimum of 21.5 in<sup>3</sup> if you're using all #14AWG wiring (on a 15a breaker). If you're using any #12 wire, you'll probably need an even bigger box. In my experience, it *never* hurts to have a bigger box, so go big if you're unsure. <sup>*No affiliation, just the first result of a search for box fill calculators.</sup>
  - The box volume must be marked somewhere on the inside of the box so you'll be able to find it when the box is installed.
  - If your ceiling box isn't big enough, you'll need to replace it, too. (The procedure is, essentially, the same as replacing the gang box where the switches go, so adapt and follow the procedures here.)
- Once you've confirmed that your box is big enough (or have replaced it):

  - Wire the "living room" in to the "living room" out cables (black-to-black, white-to-white, ground-to-ground) and push those to the back of the box.
  - Wire the "kitchen light" wire back to the kitchen light fixture (as it was before - you took a picture, right?)
  - Be sure there is *NO* connection between the living room cabling and the kitchen cabling. (Grounds can be connected, but don't need to be.)
  - Mount the kitchen light fixture back to the ceiling
- Your work on a ladder is done!

Now it's time to repair the wall/install a 3-gang box:

- If you had to cut a larger hole into the wall in order to get the box out:

  - Nail/screw in a new 3-gang box.
  - Feed your "Panel hot" into the box, as well as the "Outside", "Kitchen" and new "Living room" switched cables.
  - Be sure they're clamped appropriately for the box you're using.
  - You can pre-cut the hole in the drywall for the new box, or wait until the drywall is partially up and cut it out afterwards.
  - Replace the drywall
- Wire everything up:

  - Tie all 4 neutral wires together under one wire nut and push them to the back of the box.
  - If you're using a metal box, screw the "Panel hot" ground to the box with a 10-32 ground screw, tie all the other grounds together in a wire nut with a pig tail, screw the pig tail to the box with another 10-32 screw.
  - If you're using a plastic box, you'll need to tie all the grounds together *and* have 3 pig tails coming out to attach to each switch. (Score one for the metal box!)
  - From the "Panel hot" cable, you'll want a pig-tail with 3 outgoing tails. One will go to each switch.
  - Connect the outgoing hot cables from the "Outdoor", "Kitchen" and "Living Room" to the desired switches. One hot per switch so that each switch controls a separate light fixture.
- After making sure that all screws and wire nuts are tight, turn the breaker back on.

  - ***Carefully*** test each of the 3 switches to ensure that you've got it wired correctly and that each switch controls only the desired light.
  - Be sure to only toggle the switch and do *NOT* touch the sides or you'll get zapped. I've been zapped a couple of times and it tingles. Or, it could *kill* you.
- **Turn the breaker off.**

  - Fix any wiring that needed to be fixed and retest.
  - Carefully push the switches into the box & mount them.
  - Put your new 3-gang cover plate on
- Turn the breaker on and test again.

Congrats! You've done it!

Now all you have to do is finish the drywall repairs (and paint/wallpaper) at the new 3-gang switch and possibly on the kitchen ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to separate a ceiling fan, kitchen light, and outside light

The outside light has its own switch and nothing to do with the kitchen.

You have one switch that controls the kitchen light and the pull chain fan. Fan does not run without kitchen lights on.

Your Fan unit might or might not have separate (black) wires in the ceiling box for fan and light. In the wall box you need, 5 blacks. One with always power, is the incoming.

The one black coming from one switch to the outside light.

One black connecting the two switches (passing) the incoming power.

Two blacks going out from the switch to the ceiling box.

If you have that, you can separate the two blacks to another switch.

If not, you can not separate the fan and fan-light at the wall switch.

For that you would need to add remote controller in the ceiling box. With it you could control separately the fan and light.

Example:

[image: example remote]

[source](https://www.electrical-online.com/converting-an-existing-ceiling-fan-to-a-remote-control/)

Comment: I’m not trying to separate the fan and the fan light. I am trying to separate the whole unit from the light fixture in the kitchen. It is a separate light. I don’t think I am able to though. I am thinking that both the ceiling fan unit and light fixture in the kitchen are connect and using the same wire in the attic. I would have to unseperate them there and run another wire down to the box.

Comment: @RobertPruitt please edit your original question to make it explicitly clear that there is a fan/light combo in the living room and a light in the kitchen and that both are controlled by the same switch on the wall. TBH, it's kinda hard to follow your description of what's happening and what you really want.